# Por que 2*i*i tende a ser mais rápido que 2*(i*i) quando i é inteiro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, python-internals, cpython

As duas multiplicações, `2*i*i` e `2*(i*i)`, são iguais e devem gerar o mesmo resultado, o que muda apenas é a ordem que as multiplicações são feitas, mas aparentemente são tratadas de forma diferente pelo interpretador.

Na primeira multiplicação, dada a ausência dos parenteses e considerando que todas as operações [possuem a mesma precedência](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), o interpretador executará da esquerda para a direita; isto é, primeiro será feito `2*i` e o resultado multiplicado por `i`.

Na segunda multiplicação, dada a presença dos parênteses, a ordem de execução é alterada pois a multiplicação `i*i` passa a ter maior precedência perante a multiplicação por 2, então o interpretador primeiro fará `i*i` e o resultado multiplicará por 2.

Matematicamente, a ordem dos fatores não altera o produto, então o resultado deve ser o mesmo, porém utilizando o pacote nativo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) é possível ver uma diferença entre os tempos de execução entre essas multiplicações:

```
>>> print('2*i*i:', timeit("for i in range(1000): 2*i*i"))
2*i*i: 276.91411599100684

>>> print('2*(i*i):', timeit("for i in range(1000): 2*(i*i)"))
2*(i*i): 279.21798045100877
```

<sup>Testes foram feitos no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MysteriousWindingComputing)</sup>

> **Nota:** importante salientar que a função `timeit` executará, por padrão, 1.000.000 vezes o trecho de código indicado e que o tempo exato de execução pode variar devido a oscilações do processador e entre computadores.

Por que existe essa diferença de tempo? A presença dos parenteses na expressão altera o algoritmo executado?

Salientando que a análise deve ser feita na implementação oficial do Python, CPython, na versão 3+. Comparações com outras versões ou implementações serão bem-vindas como forma de incrementar a resposta.

Comment: Creio que seja percepção, talvez você tenha alguma ideia do que causa a variação no interpretador, mas em um teste rápido aqui o `2*(i*i)` foi mais rapido, mas isto é aquela coisa de micro-otimização, sei que eventualmente elas podem ser necessárias, mas a variação de 100ms as vezes parece muita coisa, mas em um programa nem sempre é, o que devo dizer é que por hora pode ser de fato do interpretador e outra hora pode ser ocasionado pelo sistema operacional estar ocupado com outras tarefas, sei que sua pergunta é totalmente técnica e a achei muito boa [...]

Comment: [...] mas também acredito que isto possa ser apenas uma impressão sua. Claro que você pode entender algo sobre o interpretador da linguagem que confirme essa pequena eventual variação, vou acompanhar a pergunta também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A ideia da pergunta nem é sobre otimização, mas sim sobre os algoritmos mesmo. O interpretador do Python altera o algoritmo, de fato, para fazer a multiplicação em certas condições e a diferença entre esses algoritmos que gera essa diferença de tempo - embora quase imperceptível.

Comment: Como eu disse antes, aqui com os testes os resultados foram totalmente "aleatórios", o que talvez implique a questão do uso do sistema operacional e hardware afetar em algum nível a "concorrência". Mas entendo que você talvez já tenha ideia do que cause isto especificamente, aguardarei ansioso :)

Comment: Oi Anderson, talvez valha a pena postar a exata versão do Python que você usou. A diferença é razoavelmente pequena e me cheira a variação aleatória ou pequena otimização das instruções finais emitidas para o CPU. Talvez a multiplicação por dois esteja sendo substituída por algo como `i<<1` no primeiro caso, ou talvez o interpretador emita instruções um pouco mais complicadas devido aos parênteses. Esse é o tipo de situação em que PyPy e Cython devem produzir resultados significativamente diferentes também.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Sim, por isso adicionei a tag CPython. Qualquer análise deve ser feita na implementação oficial da linguagem. Comparações com outras são bem-vindas como forma de incrementar a resposta. Sobre a versão, podemos nos ater a versão 3+. Irei adicionar a tag.

Comment: Pergunta foi fortemente inspirada em [Why is 2 * x * x faster than 2 * ( x * x ) in Python 3.x, for integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53570864/1452488)

Comment: Oi Anderson, o que eu quis dizer sobre versão específica seria 3.X.X na plataforma Y. Digo isso pois, apesar da resposta do SOEn dar bons motivos para a versão inicial ser mais rápida (diferentes algoritmos de multiplicação conforme o tamanho do número, cache de números pequenos, etc), a verdade é que localmente (Python 3.7.2rc1 no openSUSE 15 - Intel 64 bits) estou vendo resultados bem mais aleatórios. Pode ser devido a falhas naturais de *microbenchmarks*,  pode ser que algo tenha mudado no interpretador entre as versões, ou, ainda, pode ser que algo mude devido a plataforma e tipo de CPU.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly foi *"quase" exatamente* o que eu disse, a influencia do sistema operacional sob diferentes hardwares mais o uso de outros recursos que podem afetar a **concorrência** nos processos, quando citei que era micro-otimização, não quis dizer que a intenção era de fato otimizar, mas é que em muitos casos as micro-otimizações nos enganam, quando na verdade os motivos que levam a certas "micro-diferenças" são fatores externos ;)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly (cc @GuilhermeNascimento) verei se consigo redigir a pergunta então tentando eliminar esses parâmetros e deixar claro que a pergunta é exatamente sobre a troca de algoritmos em determinadas condições. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: A pergunta é muito interessante. Fiquei curioso para saber quais os fatores que estão afetando os resultados na minha máquina e "quebrando" a diferença esperada. De quebra, a pergunta apontada pelo @Anderson linka para essa outra [Why is 2 * (i * i) faster than 2 * i * i in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53452713/664577). Nesse caso eu consegui confirmar a diferença mencionada no Java 11. Os "truques" que cada compilador / interpretador usam e os efeitos de tudo que o Guilherme mencionou realmente são fascinantes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Você já sabe, mas não custa repetir" se você acha que precisa de otimizações nesse nível num trecho de código em Python, está escrevendo esse trecho de código na linguagem *errada* (ou qualquer outra linguagem de muito alto nível, como ruby, php, e mesmo Java).

Agora tem algumas coisas que dá pra responder na sua pergunta, e especular um pouco, mesmo sem chegar numa resposta definitiva.

Primeiro - quando você quer saber diferenças desse tipo em Python, vale a pena olhar qual foi o bytecode gerado para cada trecho de código. Comparando o bytecode é mais fácil especular quais podem ser as diferenças. Em Python, a função `dis` do módulo de mesmo nome permite ver o bytecode:

```
In [54]: def a(): 
    ...:     return 2 * i * i 
    ...:                                                                                                 

In [55]: def b(): 
    ...:     return 2 * (i * i) 
    ...:                                                                                                 

In [56]: import dis                                                                                      

In [57]: dis.dis(a)                                                                                      
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              8 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [58]: dis.dis(b)                                                                                      
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Então como se pode ver, de fato há uma pequena diferença: No primeiro caso, o bytecode alterna carregar os valores a serem multiplicados na pilha da máquina virtual do Python com as chamadas a multiplicação em si. No segundo caso, ele coloca todos os valores na pilha da máquina virtual, e então chama o operador de multiplicação duas vezes seguidas.
Pode ser que otimizadores em nível do microcódigo da CPU consigam otimizar essa chamada repetida em seguida a função que vai ser chamada pelo opcode `BINARY_MULTIPLY` (por exemplo, a chamada seguida pode dar mais hits na branch prediction da CPU).

De qualquer forma, se não for exatamente isso, eu ainda apostaria minhas fichas que o que acontece é exatamente alguma otimização em nível do microcode da CPU que é ativada no segundo caso.

Exatamente o tipo de coisa que você raramente vai se preocupar mesmo se estiver codificando em C, quanto mais em Python. E nesse caso, antes de dizer "nossa, deixa eu usar assembler inline", seria o caso de buscar soluções em alto-nível que pudessem user os recursos do computador de forma mais apropriada - código que use a GPU ou as unidades de processamento vetorial da CPU por exemplo, que dariam um ganho ordens de grandeza maior do que ficar micro-otimizando uma única operação. (E no caso do Python, o "primeiro" remédio sempre vai ser usar NumPy) .

Para tirar a teima se por acaso não é nada dentro do código do Pyton mesmo, só checando também o código que vai ser chamado para o BINARY_MULTIPLY - que certamente tem otimizações para quando ambos os operandos são Inteiros de Python, mas não além disso (por exemplo, uma otimização a mais se um dos operadores for '2' - de qualquer forma, o runtime tem que chamar o código que está em `int.__mul__` para isso) - mas estou falando de otimizações que vão estar entre a VM achar o opcode e chamar o `int.__mul__`.

A propósito, a diferença realmente é tão pouco significativa que  outras alterações faem as coisas mudarem - veja o que acontece quando meço os tempos para as funções `a` e `b` acima:

```
In [59]: i = 10                                                                                          

In [60]: %timeit a()                                                                                     
119 ns ± 1.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [61]: %timeit b()                                                                                     
123 ns ± 0.725 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Ou seja, nesta máquina, a forma `2 * i * i` é mais rápida!

Comment: não  - no fim nenhuma das duas é mais rápida - depende dos números que vocè está usando e da CPU - a diferença é tão pequena que a ordem é essencialmente aleatória e NUNCA, **NUNCA** , deve ser usada para uma escolha do tipo "vou fazer assim por que é mais rápido - que eu vi lá no stackoverflow". 
Se precisar fazer as operações mais rápidas, faça explicitamente em código nativo (com extenção em  C ou Cython), ou use o Numpy.